# Ubuntu - Laptop shutsdown at login after some time

Tags: boot, shutdown, login-screen

I have windows and ubuntu installed on a thinkpad L14. When I start my laptop I can choose wich OS I want to start. Windows is working properly by the way. When I reach de login screen of ubunto, after some time the laptop shutsdown.
I had this problem before and I fixed it by going into recovery mode and fixing some broken packages.
Now it's back and I can't fix it using the same method.
I don't know what is causing it so here's what happened: I used my laptop to do an online exam, in wich I connected to a network my teachers made avaiable (on ubuntu). Then I turned of my laptop and when I tried to use it again at home It wasn't working.
Below is a picture of what I got when I entered recovery mode. Maybe a graphics problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk95Y.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like a power manager setting to me.

Comment: How can I solve it?
I also tried pressing ctrl + alt + F3 to command line... Also shutsdown.

Comment: You say that when you reach the login screen AFTER SOME TIME it shuts down. Can you log in immediately as soon as the login screen appears? And what happens next (even if you can't log in)?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I started disabling drivers on BIOS. **I also had the BIOS date and time different than the ubunto** so maybe that was the reason.
Thanks for the support anyway.